# Accessing data in Android activites

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am new in using java and android. I've read about the android application life cycle and other android programming basics. I need to create an application with 5 activities and will communicate with Bluetooth reader and smart card:

1. Home - In this activity the app should check if the the Bluetooth of the phone is enabled or not. This will be first activity which will display the 4 buttons below.
2. Begin - This will ask the user to present a smart card and will check if the card is valid or not.
3. Register - this will create a new account and the information will be saved in the smart card connected to the Bluetooth reader.
   4.Select device - This will display the scanned/available Bluetooth reader in a List view. Once the user select an item, the application will go back to the Home page and the name of the Bluetooth device selected will be displayed in the Home page.
4. Device Info - This will display some information of the selected Bluetooth device.

Now, how should I implement this using listeners. From what I have read, other activity that is not visible to the user may be killed by the system to free up some memory space thus, the resources of that activity will be gone also. Is that correct? I want to implement this without having to create an instance of a reader class on each activity (if this is possible). I also thinking of creating a Parcelable class so that I can pass the reader class to other activities including the values that are needed by other activities.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve that by either creating a Parcelable class so you can pass the data to other activities via bundle or creating a static class that handles/stores data which is accessible to all of your activities.

Comment: I also think to use static class but I am not sure if the static class can hold the values pass to it and will be use by other activities. But I can assume that the static class can hold the values since you suggested to use it. Thanks for the suggestion by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty heavily contested subject among the Android community, but have you considered using Fragments?

If you are just getting started with Android, I think this approach would be entirely worthwhile. Although the Activity/Fragment life-cycle is pretty [complex](http://staticfree.info/~steve/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png), if you are serious about wanting to learn Android, dealing with Fragments (at least for now) is almost unavoidable.

Even if you end up in the Anti-Fragment group, at least you'll have your own personal experiences from which you can come up with your own opinions.

I personally think that this approach will make your life a bit easier.  If you do a Google search for "communicating between fragments" you will find a ton of examples to help get you started. When I was first getting starting, I watched a lot of the videos by slidenerd.

I just checked and he has a 3 part series about [communicating between fragments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8), and the next video after the third one is about saving/maintaining the state of your fragments.

After you get a bit more acclimated with the basics, then I would suggest ditching the listeners and learning/using RxJava.

Hope this helps, don't hesitate to come back with more questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I will search about "communicating between fragments" topic.